# ORMLite SQLite w/ Plain Java Error: "SQL error or missing database"

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, ormlite

I've been using ORMLite for months on Android in several different projects. It's been great! The other day I started backporting a project of mine that has a plain old java component that I parse some data, and create a sqlite database that I include in an android project.

I had been using a jdbc library to call plain sqlite statements, and when I swapped over to ormlite-jdbc with xerial's jdbc library, immediately my code throws an error when I try to create a table in a fresh database file:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.test.library.java.exception.BAException: java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement failed: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chapter` (`book` VARCHAR NOT NULL , `chapter` INTEGER , `chapter` VARCHAR NOT NULL , `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ) 
    at com.test.parser.Database.createTables(Database.java:109)
    at com.test.parser.Database.<init>(Database.java:81)
    at com.test.parser.runnable.TranslationParserRunnable.run(TranslationParserRunnable.java:35)
    at com.test.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:13)
    at com.test.parser.Main.main(Main.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL statement failed: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `chapter` (`book` VARCHAR NOT NULL , `chapter` INTEGER , `chapter` VARCHAR NOT NULL , `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ) 
    at com.j256.ormlite.misc.SqlExceptionUtil.create(SqlExceptionUtil.java:22)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:468)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doCreateTable(TableUtils.java:442)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTable(TableUtils.java:220)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(TableUtils.java:61)
    at com.test.parser.Database.createTables(Database.java:102)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (duplicate column name: chapter)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:383)
    at org.sqlite.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:387)
    at org.sqlite.DB.throwex(DB.java:374)
    at org.sqlite.NestedDB.prepare(NestedDB.java:134)
    at org.sqlite.DB.prepare(DB.java:123)
    at org.sqlite.PrepStmt.<init>(PrepStmt.java:42)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:404)
    at org.sqlite.Conn.prepareStatement(Conn.java:399)
    at com.j256.ormlite.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseConnection.compileStatement(JdbcDatabaseConnection.java:131)
    at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableUtils.doStatements(TableUtils.java:459)
    ... 13 more
```

To get that error, all I would have to do is:

```
public Database(File dbFile) {
    try {
      // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      throw new BAException(e);
    }

    dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    dbFile.delete();

    String connectionName = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFile.getPath();
    System.out.println("Connection Path: " + connectionName);

    try {
      mConnectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(connectionName);
      createTables();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new BAException(e);
    }

    createTables();
  }

  private  void createTables() {
    try {
      TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(mConnectionSource, ExampleTable.class);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      throw new BAException(e);
    }

  }
```

An error is thrown when I try to create the tables. The interesting thing is, if I just use straight JDBC everything works fine:

```
public Database(File dbFile) {
        try {
          // load the sqlite-JDBC driver using the current class loader
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          throw new BAException(e);
        }

        dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        dbFile.delete();

        String connectionName = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFile.getPath();
        System.out.println("Connection Path: " + connectionName);

try {
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionName);

  Statement statement = null;
  try {
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.setQueryTimeout(30);

    statement.executeUpdate(SQL.CREATE_TABLE_EXAMPLE);
    statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE \"android_metadata\" (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')");
    statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO \"android_metadata\" VALUES ('en_US')");
  } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
    try {
      if (statement != null)
        statement.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

} catch (SQLException e) {
  throw new BAException(e);
}
```

So again, that works fine, and the equivalent using ORMLite throws a missing database exception. I spent 6+ hours trying to figure this out, and it seems like the issue lies in ormlite. I noticed when running `mConnectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource(connectionName);` there is an empty database file created (at least I assume this is the line that creates it), but then I seem to lack the ability to interact with it.

I haven't been able to find any ormlite code examples interacting with sqlite using DAO's and connection sources. It seems all the jdbc examples are done using an h2 memory database.

**Any help would be wonderful.**

Some other information:
I'm building with gradle.

```
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:4.48'
compile 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.7.2'
```

Comment: This is on Android?  You should be using the Android backend for ORMLite and _not_ the JDBC, right?

Comment: For examples of Sqlite you can take a look at the ormlite-tests project which has tests that require database support.  For example: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-tests/blob/master/src/test/java/com/j256/ormlite/db/SqliteConnectTest.java

Comment: So this is not being used directly on Android. This is being used in a Java project that creates an sqlite database that is used on Android. So this is pure java. I'm converting an already working jdbc project to use ormlite.

Comment: Can you show the create table statement that is being executed?

Comment: Sorry for slow response. Added the FULL stack trace in the question, and that has the statement that's being executed.

Comment: And I see it now. I have 2 columns with the same name. A dumb mistake on my own behalf. Sorry for being stupid, and thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Really I fault sqlite for this.  If they had just had "SQL problem duplicate column name" you would not have had an issue.  It was the "missing database or..." type of error message which slowed you down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had 2 columns with the same name. After fixing that, everything worked fine. ORMLite is wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

> immediately my code throws an error when I try to create a table in a fresh database file:

So on possible problem may be that you seem to be trying to write to a *directory* instead of a database file:

```
dbFile.mkdirs();
dbFile.delete();
String connectionName = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFile.getPath();
...
```

Maybe you meant:

```
dbFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

If `dbFile` is supposed to be a directory then you need to provide a name after the file:

```
String connectionName = "jdbc:sqlite:" + dbFile.getPath() + "/db.sqlite";
```

Comment: The database file is being created just fine. I can see the database in the file system

Comment: So I guess it works because you are making the directory (and the parent) and then removing the directory and then creating it as a file.  I'd change that `mkDirs()` line at least @spierce7.

Comment: The exact same code works A-OK when I just use plain JDBC. I provided both examples. After the JDBC example I can open the file with an sqlite browser and view it just fine. Not so with the ORMLite example. I'll make your suggested changes, (I actually have tried that in my testing), but the problem seems to be in the actual  use of ORMLite. I'm fairly stumped.

Comment: Tried it out. Edited original question to match your suggestion. Still getting the error. Added the full stack trace as well. The dbFile has the file name in the path.